# Anti-Muggle sentiment post Battle of Hogwarts

Tags: harry-potter

Just browsing through Pottermore I came across a snippet about the late Astoria Greengrass.

> Draco married the younger sister of a fellow Slytherin. Astoria Greengrass, who had gone through a similar (though less violent and frightening) conversion from pure-blood ideals to a more tolerant life view, was felt by Narcissa and Lucius to be something of a disappointment as a daughter-in-law. They had had high hopes of a girl whose family featured on the 'Sacred Twenty-Eight', but as Astoria refused to raise their grandson Scorpius in the belief that Muggles were scum, family gatherings were often fraught with tension.

Here we see that anti-Muggle sentiment still exists although Astoria tries to raise her son free from it.

Do we have any other such examples of anti-Muggle sentiment existing even though the majority of the pureblood radicals were eliminated in the Second Wizarding War?

Comment: I'm pretty sure most pureblood believers survived the war. It was only Death-Eaters that died and those who directly opposed them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Hatred of Muggles would still exist.

Though the Dark Lord lost the war, wizards who hate Muggles would still exist. Wizards hating Muggles wasn’t caused by the Dark Lord, and there’s no reason to think they’d be eradicated by the war with the Dark Lord. A certain amount of wizards have hated Muggles for centuries, predating the Statute of Secrecy.

> “A pro-Muggle story showing a Muggle-loving father as superior in magic to a Muggle-hating son? It is nothing short of amazing that any copies of the original version of this tale survived the flames to which they were so often consigned.
>
> Beedle was somewhat out of step with his times in preaching a message of brotherly love for Muggles. The persecution of witches and wizards was gathering pace all over Europe in the early fifteenth century.” 
> <sub><sup>*- The Tales of Beedle the Bard*</sup></sub>

The war wouldn’t have killed off everyone with pure-blood values. The wizards who hate Muggles weren’t all actually fighting for the Dark Lord - some of even the most avid believers in the pure-blood cause just were quietly in favor of the Dark Lord.

> “Were – were your parents Death Eaters as well?’
>
> ‘No, no, but believe me, they thought Voldemort had the right idea, they were all for the purification of the wizarding race, getting rid of Muggle-borns and having pure-bloods in charge. They weren’t alone, either, there were quite a few people, before Voldemort showed his true colours, who thought he had the right idea about things … they got cold feet when they saw what he was prepared to do to get power, though.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix, Chapter 6 (The Noble and Most Ancient House of Black)*</sup></sub>

Several wizards hate Muggles, since some wizard parents avoid telling their children stories that paint Muggles in a positive light, like the original version of “The Wizard and the Hopping Pot”.

> “To this day, some Wizarding children are only told the revised version of the story by their (generally anti-Muggle) parents, and the original, if and when they ever read it, comes as a great surprise.” 
> <sub><sup>*- The Tales of Beedle the Bard*</sup></sub>

Parents requested the removal of certain stories that were too approving of Muggles, so there is a contingent of wizards who hate Muggles and want to pass their beliefs on. It’s likely at least some of them were successful at this.

> “More than one parent has demanded the removal of this particular tale from the Hogwarts library, including, by coincidence, a descendant of Brutus Malfoy and one-time member of the Hogwarts Board of Governors, Mr. Lucius Malfoy. Mr. Malfoy submitted his demand for a ban on the story in writing:
>
> *Any work of fiction or nonfiction that depicts interbreeding between wizards and Muggles should be banned from the bookshelves of Hogwarts. I do not wish my son to be influenced into sullying the purity of his bloodline by reading stories that promote wizard—Muggle marriage.*” 
> <sub><sup>*- The Tales of Beedle the Bard*</sup></sub>

Also, some of those who did fight for the Dark Lord did survive, and their beliefs didn’t necessarily change. Lucius and Narcissa Malfoy didn’t stop disliking Muggles because they lost the war or changed their minds, they just didn’t want to go to Azkaban.

> Georgina: Did lucius malfoy, and all the other escaped death eaters, go back to azkaban
>
> J.K. Rowling: No, the Malfoys weaseled their way out of trouble (again) due to the fact that they colluded (albeit out of self-interest) with Harry at the end of the battle. 
> <sub><sup>*[- Bloomsbury Live Chat (July 30, 2007)](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2007/0730-bloomsbury-chat.html)*</sup></sub>

Perhaps most importantly, there have been wizards who hate Muggles for centuries - there’s no reason to think this particular war would eliminate that from wizarding society entirely.

## The Ministry did change, however.

Though wizards who hate Muggles wouldn’t stop existing because of the war, the Ministry did indeed change as a result of the war. It was de-corrupted and its discrimination was eliminated.

> Leaky Cauldron: What, if anything, did the wizarding world learn, and how did society change, as a direct result of the war with voldemort? (i.E., not as a result of harry, ron and hermione's future careers.)
>
> J.K. Rowling: The Ministry of Magic was de-corrupted, and with Kingsley at the helm the discrimination that was always latent there was eradicated.
>
> J.K. Rowling: Harry, Ron, Hermione, Ginny et al would of course play a significant part in the re-building of wizarding society through their future careers. 
> <sub><sup>*[- Bloomsbury Live Chat (July 30, 2007)](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2007/0730-bloomsbury-chat.html)*</sup></sub>

Additionally, as part of the Department of Magical Law Enforcement, Hermione removed “pro-pure-blood” laws.

> Katieleigh: Does hermione still continue to do work with SPEW and is life any better for house elves!
>
> J.K. Rowling: Hermione began her post-Hogwarts career at the Department for the Regulation and Control of Magical Creatures where she was instrumental in greatly improving life for house-elves and their ilk. She then moved (despite her jibe to Scrimgeour) to the Dept. of Magical Law Enforcement where she was a progressive voice who ensured the eradication of oppressive, pro-pureblood laws. 
> <sub><sup>*[- Bloomsbury Live Chat (July 30, 2007)](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2007/0730-bloomsbury-chat.html)*</sup></sub>

So, the Ministry did change as a direct result of the war, and several laws were changed as well.

Answer (score 1):

It's stated in the books that the regard for Muggles is as low as ever, even people who are supposed to uphold the law think that nothing about using magic against Muggles. We can conclude that either there is no law against using magic against Muggles, or if such a law exists, even the Aurors don't think it's something that should be enforced.

At the end of book 7, Ron says to Harry:

> "Hermione didn't believe I could pass a Muggle driving test, did you? She thought I'd have to Confound the examiner."
>
> "As a matter of fact, I did Confund him," Ron whispered to Harry. (DH Epilogue)

As evidenced by Harry's non-reaction to this confession, Harry, the Head Auror, also thinks there is nothing wrong with using magic against Muggles. He is more afraid of Hermione's reaction than about the law or what society might think about his behavior.

I could say that Ron does it for personal gain, but he obviously didn't have a need for a driving license in almost twenty years, and probably still doesn't, so it seems he did it for fun.

Note that this goes even further than the point in the question, because there the disagreement is about the relative worth of Muggles compared to Wizards, and because of the Statute of Secrecy, the Muggles will never know what the Malfoys think about them. This is about taking action against Muggles, and Ron and Harry are supposed to be the good guys, so others would have even less problems with acting against Muggles.

So the sentiment that Muggles are worthless is still prevalent at least among the purebloods and the halfbloods, and as it includes the Aurors, there is no need for anybody to change.

Comment: Given that Ron can, with trivial ease, repair any damage he causes to person or property, having a valid (muggle) driving licence seems like an indulgence.

Comment: Well, unless he kills someone...

Comment: I would posit that this is just another example of a couple of guys who have *if I may say so, a certain disregard for the rules* than any anti-muggle sentiment.

Answer (score 0):

It's stated in the books that Harry and Ron revolutionized the Auror office and with Hermione being elected Minister of Magic it's clear that the Wizarding World is progressing towards a more liberal future.

There are of course hardliners like Malfoy who still hold on to their racist beliefs in the face of a changing world but they are few and far between.